# Multiple versions of JQuery on the same page not working

Tags: jquery

Actually I am looking for clientside checkbox control + scrollable gridview for my asp.net project. I got a good article from http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo/Form.aspx#CheckBoxClient. I have posted the code as given below which, I have taken from the above website. Here only the fixed header with scrollable function is working perfectly but CheckBox Client-Side not working. Can any one help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
gridviewScroll();
});

function gridviewScroll() {
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
width: 660,
height: 200,
freezesize: 3
});

var cbSelecteds1 = "cbSelecteds1_freezeheader";
var cbSelected1 = "<%=GridView1.ClientID%>_cbSelected1";

CheckBoxCheckAll(cbSelecteds1, cbSelected1);

var cbSelecteds2 = "cbSelecteds2_Copy";
var cbSelected2 = "<%=GridView1.ClientID%>_cbSelected2";

CheckBoxCheckAll(cbSelecteds2, cbSelected2);
}

function CheckBoxCheckAll(checkboxs, checkbox)
{
$('#' + checkboxs).change(function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
$('input[id*="' + checkbox + '"]').attr('checked', checked);
});

$('input[id*="' + checkbox + '"]').change(function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
if (!checked) {
$('#' + checkboxs).attr('checked', false);
}
else {
var allchecked = true;
$('input[id*="' + checkbox + '"]').each(function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
if (!checked) {
allchecked = false;
}
});
$('#' + checkboxs).attr('checked', allchecked);
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple jQuery versions?

Comment: You should only use 1 version of jQuery. When you include more than 1, they will conflict with each other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

You are using live() method and linking the library version greater than 1.7 which is deprecated. Use [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Or, to make live() method work, you need to link the jquery library version below 1.7.

---

**Recommendation:**

Just use only one version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you include multiple `jquery`s? You should only have one. It will be loaded into the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should use only one jQuery version. I'd suggest the later version.

However, if you've no choice then you'll need to look at **[jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

So in your case, you can keep `$` sign for the code which are using version `1.8.3`.

For version `1.8.2`, you can use no conflict mode like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var jQuery_1_8_2 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_1_8_2(document).ready(function () { 
gridviewScroll();                     
}); 

function gridviewScroll() { 
jQuery_1_8_2('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({ 
width: 960, 
height: 200, 
railcolor: "#F0F0F0",
barcolor: "#CDCDCD",
barhovercolor: "#606060",
bgcolor: "#F0F0F0",
freezesize: 3,
arrowsize: 30,
varrowtopimg: "Images/arrowvt.png",
varrowbottomimg: "Images/arrowvb.png",
harrowleftimg: "Images/arrowhl.png",
harrowrightimg: "Images/arrowhr.png",
railsize: 16,
barsize: 8 
});    
}                
</script>
```

Comment: thank u so much. tried as per u have suggested. right now gridviewscroll function is working. check all function (i.e) 1.8.3 not working

Comment: Try to do the same way for `1.8.3` using no conflict mode